# Bind datasource at the time of api call Spring boot Jpa

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, architecture

I am planning to launch a product in three different markets and manage the three different database for application.

Technology stack has been chosen as Spring-Boot. Need to connect database on the basis of parameter region coming in request.

Can anyone please help me how this can be done in spring Jpa?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [AbstractRoutingDatasource](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/lookup/AbstractRoutingDataSource.html) , spring for multiple datasource routing

you can follow this intersting [tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-abstract-routing-data-source) or see in the official doc [here](https://spring.io/blog/2007/01/23/dynamic-datasource-routing) ( becarful official article is too old dated from 2007 also uses xml config )